# Unable to auto set BackgroundColor in TopAppBar in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a theme like this.

```
@Composable
fun WorkoutTimerTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),

    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = false,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }
        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }
    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            (view.context as Activity).window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()
            ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(view)?.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
        }
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}
```

I override every single color for DarkColorScheme and LightColorScheme to Color.Red. Then I create my activity content like this.

```
setContent {
    val darkTheme =
        dataStoreUtil.getForceDarkTheme.collectAsState(initial = darkThemeInitialValue).value

    WorkoutTimerTheme(darkTheme = darkTheme) {
        //val navController = rememberNavController()

        Scaffold(
            topBar = {
                TopAppBar(
                    navigationIcon = {
                        IconButton(onClick = { this.onBackPressed() }) {
                            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
                                contentDescription = null,
                                Modifier.alpha(0.8f)
                            )
                        }
                    },
                    title = {
                        Text(getString(R.string.title_activity_settings),
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6)
                    },
                )
            },
```

Why my TopAppBar background color always look like this? (violet) Why never Red? What's the point?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use ***backgroundColor*** property of TopAppBar

```
topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = { this.onBackPressed() }) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
                            contentDescription = null,
                            Modifier.alpha(0.8f)
                        )
                    }
                },
                title = {
                    Text(getString(R.string.title_activity_settings),
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6)
                },
                backgroundColor = Red,
                contentColor = White,
            )
        },
```

Modify color according to theme in this property

Comment: Yes, sure, I know that.. But the point is... Why is it not extending colors like a Text, Switch... like any other controls? Why everything works except TopAppBar?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I was using Material Theme 3 but TopAppBar is a Material Theme 2 component.

SmallTopAppBar, MediumTopAppBar, LargeTopAppBar, etc, extends colors correctly.